# why socket.gethostbyname(socket.getfqdn()) and socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()) return differently?

Tags: sockets, networking

I know what are fqdn and hostname. But I still don't understand why this two snippets return different results. 
The `socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())` returns an ip address which is actually my ethernet adapter ip address seen with the ipconfig command on my Windows. But `socket.gethostbyname(socket.getfqdn())` returns an ip address I can't seen in the ipconfig display, neither ethernet nor ppp. What is it? 
Is the result of the gethostname the ip address relative to my local network and getfqdn relative to the whole net?
Which one of the two should I use if I'm in a remote network and wanna connect my computer or I'm in the same network with my computer? 
And actually when I try this two snippets offline, both of them return 127.0.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

when you execute those commands offline, you get 127.0.0.1 because in your /etc/hosts, the default mapping is: 127.0.0.1    localhost. So, you're `gethostname()` is resolved to localhost and `gethostbyname()` is 127.0.0.1.

I believe that, `gethostbyname()` would return the IP of the parent domain name or the IP of the fully qualified domain name for getfqdn() and gethostname() respectively. It could be different or not.